# Confusion about remap_pfn_range

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am going through remap_pfn_range and confuse about very first comment on it from kernel Source.

```
/**
* remap_pfn_range - remap kernel memory to userspace
* @vma: user vma to map to
* @addr: target user address to start at
* @pfn: physical address of kernel memory
* @size: size of map area
* @prot: page protection flags for this mapping
*
*  Note: this is only safe if the mm semaphore is held when called.
 */
```

I am confuse about the fact that how can kernel memory/pages can be remapped into user space (Kernel memory/pages contains different section of kernel and should not be remapped)

Is it like remap_pfn_range maps part of system ram other than kernel memory  ?

Comment: It maps physical address to userspace vma. What is the problem with that?

Comment: It says it map Kernel memory and I assume that Kernel memory is nothing but kernel pages so we can't remap it, it should only be remapping free pages, isn't it ?

Comment: Why we can't remap kernel pages? At low level remapping is MMU business, it works in terms of privilege levels. If you have page mapped with kernel privileges, what can stop you from creating another mapping for this page with user space privileges? Keep in mind that you can do this only from kernel.

Comment: I think poor understanding on MMU is not allowing me to see through what you are pointing out. This is something going through my mind. Kernel is always loaded and be there in System RAM so that part of the RAM can't be used for buffer allocated through kmalloc or whatever.So, to find these buffer we need to look part of RAM other than where Kernel is placed and remap_pfn_page would make those buffers and mapped it to user space address space.I wish you can see what I am thinking (which may be wrong).

Comment: That is wrong of course. http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging grep privelege level

Comment: kernel pages is not the only one where kernel is resides. Linux maps huge amount of memory (so called lowmem) at boot time and mark all this mappings as kernel mappings. Further, when slab allocator (kmalloc) is inited, it can use this pre-mapped pages for caches creation & managing.

Comment: Read this https://lwn.net/Articles/75174/

Comment: Thanks for the Links, so you mean to say, kernel pages = pages_where_kernel_mapped + page_can_be_used_for_allocator ?

Comment: I mean yes, but kernel pages = pages_where_kernel_mapped + page_can_be_used_for_allocator + many other things. You can alloc page and map it to kernel address space for any use. Or you can use vmalloc. See Figure 4.1 https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand007.html